# Remove period after author in APA style

Tags: biblatex, apa-style

I want to change the APA style slightly for my thesis in university. I'm fine with everything it does but I would like to eliminate one little thing. For internet sources, I often use a company name or proper noun as the author to reference the source. However, `biblatex` now also places a period after these, as with the author abbreviations. I believe there should be a way with `\renewbibmacro*` but I know far too little about it to rewrite the macro. Does anyone know a way to omit this dot if there is only one word in the author attribute, as in the example below?

**Relevant information:**

Example Document:

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt,toc=bibliography]{srcreprt}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa,citestyle=apa]{biblatex}
\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes}
\addbibresource{bibliographie.bib}
\begin{document}
    Here is some text with some quotes.\autocite[12]{uml_official}

    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Example bibliography.bib

```
@misc{uml_official,
    title = "OMG Unified Modeling Language - Version 2.5.1",
    url = "https://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.5.1/PDF",
    urldate = "2021-04-28",
    year = "2017",
    author = "{OMG}"
}
```

What the current bibliography looks like:

> ***OMG. (2017).** OMG Unified Modeling Language - Version 2.5.1. [...]*

What it should look like:

> ***OMG (2017).** OMG Unified Modeling Language - Version 2.5.1. [...]*

Comment: Just to avoid confusion, I'm pretty sure that the period even after corporate authors is correct APA style, c.f. e.g. https://apastyle.apa.org/style-grammar-guidelines/references/examples/webpage-website-references.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The period after a corporate author appears to be correct APA style, see e.g. https://apastyle.apa.org/style-grammar-guidelines/references/examples/webpage-website-references#4. So I would consider not changing this.

Anyway, the following small change of `author/editor` from `\newunit\newblock` to `\setunit{\addspace}\newblock` should help.

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt,toc=bibliography]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa]{biblatex}
\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes}

\renewbibmacro*{author/editor}{%
  \ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{author}\AND\ifnameundef{groupauthor}}
    {\ifnameundef{editor}
      {\usebibmacro{title}%
        % need to clear all title fields so we don't get them again later
        \clearfield{title}%
       \clearfield{subtitle}%
       \clearfield{titleaddon}}
      {\usebibmacro{editorinauthpos}}}
    {\usebibmacro{author}}%
  \setunit{\addspace}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{labelyear+extradate}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{uml_official,
    title   = {{OMG} Unified Modeling Language - Version 2.5.1},
    url     = {https://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.5.1/PDF},
    urldate = {2021-04-28},
    year    = {2017},
    author  = {{OMG}},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
  Here is some text with some quotes.\autocite[12]{uml_official}
  Lorem\autocite{sigfridsson,aksin}

  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: OMG (2017). OMG unified modeling language - version 2.5.1. Retrieved April 28, 2021, from https://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.5.1/PDF//Sigfridsson, E., & Ryde, U. (1998). Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments. Journal of Computational Chemistry, 19(4), 377–395. https://doi.org/10.1002/(SICI)1096-987X(199803)19:4h377::AID-JCC1i3.0.CO;2-P]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification as well as for the solution. Unfortunately, the professors at our university all have different views on citation styles and don't take the official guidelines that seriously. My professor criticized the dot, so I intended to remove it for him.